# Python ProgressBar tqdm

Tags: python, progress-bar, tqdm

I want to have a progressBar wrapper object from the tqdm object which is disabled by default and can be enabled by condition. Furthermore it should work in console and jupyter notebook/lab/ipython. Therefore tqdm has a auto detection. I wrote a class:

```
class ProgressBar(object):
    import time
    import numpy as np
    from tqdm import tnrange
    from tqdm.auto import tqdm
    def __init__(self,maxValue,minValue=0):
        self.minValue=minValue
        self.maxValue=maxValue
        self.progressBar = self.createProgressBar()
    def updateBar(self,updatedValue):
        self.progressBar.update(updatedValue)
    def createProgressBar(self):
        bar = tqdm(total=self.maxValue,desc='Loading:',disable=True)
        return bar
```

But if i want to have access to the bar

```
a = ProgressBar(1000)
a.progressBar.disable=False
while True:
    fileEvaluated = np.random.randint(4,size=1)[0]
    a.updateBar(fileEvaluated)
    time.sleep(0.5)
```

i get an error message:

```
AttributeError: 'tqdm_notebook' object has no attribute 'sp'
```

Any idea what im doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do something like the following, which was tested and works on Python 3.7 Windows.

One of the reasons it probably was not working for you is that you were disabling the progress bar `bar = tqdm(total=self.maxValue,desc='Loading:',disable=True)`but then you tried enabling it with `a.progressBar.disable=False` but the class you made does not contain a disable attribute.

In order to wrap it around something it needs to be an iterable as shown in the code I posted. You probably don't need the `time.sleep()` code, I just put it there so you can see the progress bar in action, otherwise it would finish too quickly.

Also it is typically not a good idea to put import statements inside a class. If your module will always import another module, imports should be placed at the very top according to PEP 8.

EDIT: If you only want the progress bar to run after some condition then place the `update()` call nested after a conditional as shown below.

```
from tqdm import tqdm
import time


class ProgressBar(object):  # Python3+ '(object)' can be omitted
    def __init__(self, max_value, disable=True):
        self.max_value = max_value
        self.disable = disable
        self.p = self.pbar()

    def pbar(self):
        return tqdm(
            total=self.max_value,
            desc='Loading: ',
            disable=self.disable
        )

    def update(self, update_value):
        self.p.update(update_value)

    def close(self):
        self.p.close()


max_val = 1000
some_condition = True

p = ProgressBar(max_value=max_val, disable=False)

if some_condition:
    for i in range(max_val):
        time.sleep(0.01)
        p.update(1)
    p.close()
```

You can also do the same thing as above but without making your own class and shorten the amount of code.

```
from tqdm import tqdm
import time

max_val = 1000
some_condition = True

p = tqdm(total=max_val, disable=False)

if some_condition:
    for i in range(max_val):
        time.sleep(0.01)
        p.update(1)
    p.close()
```

Comment: Thank you for your approach. But the thing is, i first want to initial the progressBar disabled, and then in my code if some condition is triggered it should be enabled. So initialize it with p = ProgressBar(max_value=max_value, disable=True) and then p.disable=False

Comment: The tqdm disable feature is not really an option you can change after an instance of the tqdm class has been made. It could probably be done if you dug through the source code for the progress bar but what you ask for can easily be achieved by placing the the part of your code the progress bar will track nested in a conditional statement. I edited the very bottom of the code slightly.

Answer (score 1):

it work for me when I change  the import function:

```
from tqdm.notebook import tqdm
```

to

```
from tqdm import tqdm
```